# Server email services

Tags: web-applications, email

I am developing a web app that relies on the ability to send thousands of emails a day. I need to use these emails to stand as alerts for people who subscribe which mandates that it be done real time.

My question is regarding service providers placing a cap on how many emails can be sent per day (seems to be around 250). I have found that I can use a white-listed server to send the emails but I am not certain of either how this works or if it is possible to do it in real time (the people I have talked to said they send a "batch" of requests once per day).

I am looking for an answer that can explain how to use a white-listed server (I do not need gritty details, just the concept as I have not actually determined exactly how I am going to be set up yet) and also if these can be used real time so that the email is received within a minute or so of sending.

Details on this seem to be very scarce, so I may actually be misinformed or looking for the wrong answers. help appreciated :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either host mail yourself or go with an [email service provider](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E-mail_service_provider).  The choice is determined by cost and volume.  Typically newsletters or periodicals are farmed out to third parties and notification messages are kept in house.

So for an email service provider, simply choose one and read their guidelines and pricing plan.  There is [a review of service providers](http://groundwire.org/resources/articles/email-service-provider-comparison-report-2010) available here from 2010 that might provide a good overview.

Comment: Thanks. 1 spin-off question. I can host it myself provided I have the authority to do so on the server I use?   and the article is very useful as a reference at least. thanks again.

Comment: @Andy correct, now the reliability of getting inhouse email through to the client, and not the spam folder, is another question often asked here.  This is why it is good to start with less important messages and inform the user to check their spam folder.

Comment: If you're going to host it yourself, definitely look into correct SPF records, DKIM signing, and making sure your email templates do not fall into any SpamAssassin spam-phrases.